# How to make custom caption (1, 2, 3, 4)

Tags: numbering, captions

I'm trying to make a before/after figure comparison. I have 10 groups, each has 4 samples I want to compare by lining them up.

Below is the code for group 1.1. Each has 4 samples. (1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4)
I want to mark each figure with 1, 2, 3 and 4 inside each group.

> sample11.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,icelandic]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.PDF,.JPEG,.JPG,.PNG,.GIF}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}{./photo/1/}{./photo/2/}}
\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}[H]{0.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=54mm, angle=270]{photo/1/111.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[H]{0.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=54mm, angle=270]{photo/1/112.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[H]{0.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=54mm, angle=270]{photo/1/113.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[H]{0.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=54mm, angle=270]{photo/1/114.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Group Samples 1.1 before}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}[H]{0.24\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=54mm, angle=270]{photo/2/111.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[H]{0.24\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=54mm, angle=270]{photo/2/112.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[H]{0.24\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=54mm, angle=270]{photo/2/113.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[H]{0.24\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=54mm, angle=270]{photo/2/114.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Group Samples 1.1 after}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Currently it looks like picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x8bg.png) and I want it to look like picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpQNm.png)

[image: How it looks now:]

[image: How I want it to look like:]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the number manually below the picture (inside the minipage):

```
\begin{minipage}[H]{0.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{photo/2/111.jpg}
    \vskip2ex \Large 1
\end{minipage}
```

But maybe you should have a look at packages like [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)...

Comment: Thanks. So simple! :D - 
One problem though. There is no gap between the figure and the text written. Writing \\ doesn't work.

Comment: Try `\vskip2ex`

Comment: Nice, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :D